# convert two columns into dictionary by category python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to convert two columns into a dictionary, one of the is the category and the other one in a comment.

| category | comment |
| --- | --- |
| complain | did not like his attention |
| complain | I would never use this again |
| congrats | you are the best |
| request | I need my papers |

the idea is to convert that into a dictionary grouped by category, what I mean is something like this

```py
Diccionario= {
    "complain":[
        'did not like his attention', 
        'I would never use this again'
    ],
    "congrats":[
        'you are the best'
    ],
    "request":[
        'I need my papers'
    ],
    
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby.agg(list)` and `to_dict`

```
df.groupby('category')['commet'].agg(list).to_dict()

{'complain': ['did not like his attention', 'I would never use this again'],
 'congrats': ['you are the best'],
 'request': ['I need my papers']}
```